# Bestseller list and catalog_product_flat_1 in Magento

Tags: magento

I get error when setting Use Flat Catalog Product to Yes in Magento 1.8. One of my modules does not seem compatible with this function. See the following error:

> a:5:{i:0;s:1852:"SELECT SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) AS `ordered_qty`,
>   `order_items`.`name` AS `order_items_name`, `order_items`.`product_id`
>   AS `entity_id`, `e`.`entity_type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`,
>   `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`required_options`,
>   `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`updated_at`, `flat`.`name`, `flat`.`image` AS
>   `small_image`, `flat`.`price`, `flat`.`minimal_price`,
>   `flat`.`special_price`, `flat`.`special_from_date`,
>   `flat`.`special_to_date`, `cat_index`.`position` AS
>   `cat_index_position`, `at_inventory_in_stock`.`is_in_stock` AS
>   `inventory_in_stock` FROM `sales_flat_order_item` AS `order_items` 
>   INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON `order`.entity_id =
>   order_items.order_id AND `order`.state <> 'canceled' AND
>   (`order`.created_at BETWEEN '2014-01-18' AND '2014-02-17')  LEFT JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON (e.type_id NOT IN ('grouped',
>   'configurable', 'bundle')) AND e.entity_id = order_items.product_id
>   AND e.entity_type_id = 4  LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `flat`
>   ON (e.entity_id = flat.entity_id )   INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON
>   cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND
>   cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2'  INNER
>   JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_inventory_in_stock` ON
>   (at_inventory_in_stock.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND
>   ((at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND
>   at_inventory_in_stock.manage_stock=1 AND
>   at_inventory_in_stock.is_in_stock=1) OR
>   (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND
>   at_inventory_in_stock.manage_stock=0) OR
>   (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 1 AND
>   at_inventory_in_stock.is_in_stock=1)) WHERE (parent_item_id IS NULL)
>   GROUP BY `order_items`.`product_id` HAVING
>   (SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) > 0) ORDER BY `ordered_qty` desc,
>   `ordered_qty` desc LIMIT 1
>
> ";i:1;s:4869:"#0
>   /home2/icast.sajtpro.se/www/mxfoto/magento/includes/src/Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql.php(110):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

In the list.phtml file I have the following code:

```
class Tatva_Catalogextensions_Block_Bestsellers_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List {
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')             ->addOrderedQty()
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            //->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
            ->setPageSize($this->get_prod_count())
            ->setOrder($this->get_order(), $this->get_order_dir())
            ->setCurPage($this->get_cur_page());
                    $productFlatData = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/flat_catalog_product');       if($productFlatData == "1")         {           $products->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                    array('flat' => 'catalog_product_flat_1'),
                    "(e.entity_id = flat.entity_id ) ",
                    array(
                       'flat.name AS name','flat.image AS small_image','flat.price AS price','flat.minimal_price as minimal_price','flat.special_price as special_price','flat.special_from_date AS special_from_date','flat.special_to_date AS special_to_date'
                    )
                );      }

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);

        $this->_productCollection = $products;

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }

    function get_prod_count()   {       //unset any saved limits
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsLimitPage();
        return (isset($_REQUEST['limit'])) ? intval($_REQUEST['limit']) : 9;    }// get_prod_count

    function get_cur_page()     {       return (isset($_REQUEST['p'])) ? intval($_REQUEST['p']) : 1;    }// get_cur_page

    function get_order()    {       return (isset($_REQUEST['order'])) ? ($_REQUEST['order']) : 'ordered_qty';  }// get_order

    function get_order_dir()    {       return (isset($_REQUEST['dir'])) ? ($_REQUEST['dir']) : 'desc';     }// get_direction }

?>
```

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
```

to:

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_sold_collection')
```